# How to configure the admin and graph services for installing a Galaxybase cluster

Tags: graph-databases

I have 3 machines and I want high availability services. How should I deploy the admin and graph services

Galaxybase supports the deployment of admin and graph services to all nodes in the cluster.Therefore, in order to meet high availability, the admin service and graph service can be deployed on all three machines

Answer (score 1):

Galaxy base supports the deployment of admin and graph services to all nodes in the cluster

Therefore, in order to meet high availability, the admin service and graph service can be deployed on all three machines